# How bobril translation import/export works in bobril-build?

Tags: bobril

How bb translation works together?
When I used **bb b -l 1** worked fine but there is still needed to rewrite all strings for other languages.
**bb t -a** adds new language, e.g. "cs-CZ" and creates json file with language code.
The question is how can I export/import all strings into json file to translation?
**bb t -e**  - fileName is json or js in dist? Export doesn't work in my case no strings are exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bb t -e filename.txt -l cs-CZ` is correct way to export untranslated strings to text file with very simple structure. After it will get back from translation agency you can just import it by `bb t -i filename.txt -l cs-CS`.
Before exporting always update translation files by `bb b -l 1 -u 1` as you already find out. Actual JSON files in `translations` directory contains array of arrays of 3 or 4 items [original, hint, 0/1 - with/out parameters, translation]. So you can directly translate them if you will create some editor for these...

Also please update bobril-build to 0.56.1, I just fixed wrong error message in export even-though everything was ok. Maybe that confuse you so you have to ask, sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks to you for response. BB and translations working perfectly now. Good feature which will save my time.